# Fortify sourceanalyzer stuck on calculating dataflow results

Tags: fortify

I'm trying to run a Fortify analysis on a large c/c++ project, [Kamailio SIP Server](https://github.com/kamailio).
I've had it running since sometime Friday and it is now Monday.  Since Saturday, its been stuck at `calculating dataflow results (-) 1% [   ]`

I look a look at the logs and it looks like it is finding issues, but each issue is taking 30+ minutes

> Issue root [Issue Read pmod_data. [Read pmod_data->pmohq_lst[].mohq_uri] :: [->strlen(0.*) @ mohq_funcs.c:2861] {DACEC7D4} ] took 112 minutes to expand.
>
>   [2018-01-15 09:01:25.450 Thread-311 Master WARNING]
>   Issue root [Issue Read pmod_data. [Read pmod_data->pmohq_lst[].mohq_uri] :: [->strcpy(1.*) @ mohq_funcs.c:2868] {C5F8BA55} ] took 113 minutes to expand.

To run the analysis I used this command after compiling the source with the appropriate fortify hooks:

`sourceanalyzer -Xmx20000M -b test5 -scan -f test5.fpr`

Its running on a c3.xlarge EC2 instance.

Is there anything I can do to make it run faster?

Answer (score 0):

You can either add more memory options, or you can limit the depth of the analysis (There are .config file for that, you can fine tune the variables. See what configuration settings are in the .config files). check out the

> -autoheap

option as well. Sourceanalyzer -h shows some the Memory options.